# Input number and display the Input Fields according to the number inputed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, forms

I want to display the number of input box according to the number inputed in the how many.

My code is not working

```
<input id="howmany" />
<div id="boxquantity"></div>
```

Jquery/JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $('#howmany').change(function(){
        for(i=0; i < $("#howmany").value; i++)
        {
            $('#boxquantity').append('<input name="boxid[]" type="file" id="boxid[]" size="50"/>'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are appending new elements.  You're never removing any of the previously appended elements

Comment: So what is the issue? `console.log()` is your friend

Comment: Also use `.val()` not `.value` as jQuery does not directly expose properties

Comment: And don't repeat ids like `boxid[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code, without jQuery.

Built the HTML into a variable and then appended to the DOM in a single go.

```
var boxes = "";

document.getElementById("howmany").onchange = function() {
  boxes = "";
  var howmany = document.getElementById("howmany").value;
  for(i=0;i<howmany;i++) {
    boxes += '<b>File ' + i + '</b>: <input type="file" id="box' + i + ' name="box' + i + ' /><br/>';
  }
  console.log(boxes);
  document.getElementById("boxquantity").innerHTML = boxes;
}
```

Here is a [JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/geliluhodi/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the code is it's using .value on a jquery object. I replaced the $("#howmany").value **with $("#howmany").val()**

I also added a remove function to clear the number of inputs displayed.

Do run the snippet, thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#howmany').change(function() {
    $("#boxquantity input").remove();
    
    for (i = 0; i < $("#howmany").val(); i++) {
      $('#boxquantity').append('<input name="boxid['+i+']" type="file" id="boxid['+i+']" size="50"/>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="howmany" />
<div id="boxquantity"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `value` with `val`. You can replace `$("#howmany").value` with `$(this).val()`. Also each input should have unique `id`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#howmany').change(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
      $('#boxquantity').append('<input name="boxid[]" type="file" id="boxid[]_' + i + '" size="50"/>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="howmany" />
<div id="boxquantity"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st: use `type="number"` for input

2nd: for realtime use `on('input',)` instead of `.change` event *`.change` works like `.on('blur' ,)`*

3rd: use `.val()` instead of `.value`

4th: you need to reset the `#boxquantity` div when number is change .. for me it'll be better to save the inputs html to variable then use `.html()` instead of `.append()` .. OR you can use `$('#boxquantity').html('');` before the for loop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#howmany').on('input',function() {
    var Inputs = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < $("#howmany").val(); i++) {
      Inputs += '<input name="boxid[]" type="file" size="50"/>';
    }
    $('#boxquantity').html(Inputs);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="howmany" />
<div id="boxquantity"></div>
```